# reordering priority_queue based on condition c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, priority-queue

I am trying to reorder priority_queue based on user demand.

This is the data struct:

```cpp
struct Person { 

    int age; 

    float height; 
};
```

I used this struct separately to reorder it in a decreasing way

```
struct CompareHeight { 
    bool operator()(Person const& p1, Person const& p2) 
    { 
        // return "true" if "p1" is ordered  
        // before "p2", for example: 
        return p1.height > p2.height; 
    } 
} HI;
```

and I used this struct separately to reorder it in an increasing way

```
struct CompareHeightInv { 
    bool operator()(Person const& p1, Person const& p2) 
    { 
        // return "true" if "p1" is ordered  
        // before "p2", for example: 
        return p1.height < p2.height; 
    } 
} HD;
```

and I call each speratlly by:

```cpp
priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, CompareHeightInv> inc; 

priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, CompareHeight > dec;
```

My question is: is there a way that like this

```
class Foo {
private:
     ...
     priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, something> myQueue; 
     ...
public:
     Foo (bool flag) {
          if (flag)
             myQueue is increasing
          else
             myQueue is deacreasing
     }

}
```

Comment: Edit your question, instead of commenting

Comment: If `str` is constexpr, then you could use `if constexpr`. If not, then you'll need to generify your code so it's priority queue agnostic. If `str` is constexpr, you can also use `std::conditional_t<str == "increasing", CompareHeightInv, CompareHeight>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way and probably simplest, is to pass additional flag to your comparator and have only one:

```
struct CompareHeight { 
    CompareHeight( bool asc ) : ascending( asc ) {}
    bool operator()(Person const& p1, Person const& p2) 
    { 
        if(ascending) return p1.height < p2.height; 
        return p1.height > p2.height; 
    } 
    bool ascending;
};
```

then use it:

```
CompareHeight comparator( str == "increasing" );
priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, CompareHeight> queue( comparator );
```

or just one line:

```
priority_queue<Person, vector<Person>, CompareHeight> queue( CompareHeight( str == "increasing" ) );
```

Otherwise you can use `std::function` as a type and pass specific type or use inheritance and have both comparators to derive from common base. Both ways are significantly more verbose.